# Harvard Style with Vol. , No. and pp in Reference List

Tags: biblatex, natbib

I am struggling to find some guidance to use the Harvard referencing style by Emerald journals. However, I could not figure it out that how I can use it. I want reference like this,

> Capizzi, M.T. and Ferguson, R. (2005), "Loyalty trends for the twenty-first century", Journal of Consumer Marketing, Vol. 22 No. 2, pp.72-80.

but what I am getting is looks like this.

> Capizzi, M.T. and Ferguson, R. (2005), 'Loyalty trends for the twenty-first century', Journal of Consumer Marketing, 22,2, pp.72-80.

i have tried `authoryear` option in biblatex and `agsm` in `natbib`, but nothing worked yet.

Comment: If this is for journal submission, double check if the journal has a LaTeX template or at least LaTeX instructions. Usually publishers accept BibTeX-generated bibliographies but are not as happy to receive `biblatex` bibliographies, because the latter require a very different workflow. Unless the instructions specifically mention `biblatex` I would not use it.

Comment: I just checked the guidelines for an Emerald journal I picked randomly (*Accounting, Auditing & Accountability Journal*). It says "You are welcome to use the Harvard style Emerald has adopted – we’ve provided a detailed guide below. Want to use a different Harvard style? That’s fine, our typesetters will make any necessary changes to your manuscript if it is accepted." So you can probably do whatever, i.e. take `agsm` and be done with it.